Stopping a dash server inside a thread does not work
I'm trying to stop a dash server within a thread, but it doesn't work:
Here's a minor example of the issue :
import threading
import requests
from dash import Dash, html
from flask import Flask, request
import logging
import time

# Setup Logger
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)s, %(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)

# Create Flask server and associate it with the Dash app
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
app = Dash(__name__, server=flask_app)

# Define a simple layout
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
    html.P(children='This is a simple Dash app for testing.'),
    html.Button('Click Me', id='button')
])

# Define a shutdown route
@app.server.route('/shutdown', methods=['POST'])
def shutdown():
    shutdown_server = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if shutdown_server is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    shutdown_server()
    return 'Server shutting down...'

# Function to run the server
def run_server():
    logging.info("Starting Dash server")
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)

# Function to stop the server
def stop_server():
    logging.info("Sending shutdown request")
    try:
        requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8050/shutdown')
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"Error sending shutdown request: {e}")
    logging.info("Joining server thread")
    server_thread.join()

# Start the server in a new thread
server_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_server)
server_thread.start()

# Start the server, wait a few seconds, then stop it
time.sleep(5)
stop_server()
logging.info("Server stopped")

When I run this script, the program hangs at server_thread.join() and does not exit. Using kill pid is not practical for me because I am running my program within a GUI application. Killing the pid would destroy the gui as well.

Sorry for asking. What did you mean when you were saying that "Killing the pid would destroy the gui as well.". GUI is part of the web browser. Web browser will persist the site until you'll try to refresh it.

I have a Qt application that starts a simulation. When it finishes, it invokes a dash web server that displays the results in a graph. If I use os.kill(os.getpid()..), I would kill the web server (results of the simulation) and the Qt application as they both use the same process.

That's why you should use multiprocessing and spawn a new process.

I was thinking if there's a solution without using multiprocessing but guess that's what I'm going to do, thanks for the feedback.

How about starting flask_app as a separate process instead of a thread. And then kill this process using pid.

from dash import Dash, html
from flask import Flask, request
import logging
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process
import os

# Setup Logger
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)s, %(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)

# Create Flask server and associate it with the Dash app
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
app = Dash(__name__, server=flask_app)

# Define a simple layout
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
    html.P(children='This is a simple Dash app for testing.'),
    html.Button('Click Me', id='button')
])


# Define a shutdown route
@app.server.route('/shutdown', methods=['POST'])
def shutdown():
    proc = current_process()


# Function to run the server
def run_server():
    logging.info("Starting Dash server")
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)


# Function to stop the server
def stop_server(pid):
    logging.info("Sending shutdown request")
    os.kill(pid, 9)
    # requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8050/shutdown')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # Start the server in a new thread
    server_proc = Process(target=run_server, 
                            name='dash_server', 
                            daemon=True)

    server_proc.start()
    pid = server_proc.pid
    # Start the server, wait a few seconds, then stop it
    time.sleep(5)
    stop_server(pid)
    logging.info("Server stopped")
    time.sleep(30)

To kill process on Windows try replacing with this lines:
import signal
os.kill(pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
# or signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT


Thanks for the answer. However Im working under Windows and pthread_kill will not work for me :/

@James updated my answer. Could this solution work for you?
